# Airflow cron schedule interval not triggering DAG

Tags: python, cron, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Note: The crontab.guru links were breaking so I wrapped them in code blocks.

I have a DAG that is to be executed on Mondays at midnight pacific time, 8am UTC, bumped by 1 minute to avoid any overlap issues.

Originally the schedule interval was set as `1 8 */1 * 1` which according to `https://crontab.guru/#1_8_*/1_*_1` is "At 08:01 UTC (03:01 EST, 00:01 PST) on every day-of-month if it's on Monday".

However, this caused the DAG to trigger every day at 08:01 UTC; the Monday condition seemed to be ignored.

The schedule interval was updated to the simpler `1 8 * * 1`, which according to `https://crontab.guru/#1_8_*_*_1` is "At 08:01 UTC (03:01 EST, 00:01 PST) on Monday".

This stopped the DAG from executing every day, but it did not trigger on 2019-02-18, the first Monday following the update. I've read some other posts that indicate that the start date might cause this issue, but this task's start date is `datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, pytz.UTC)`, which is two intervals before the 2019-02-18 run date.

Here is the complete DAG/task definition (without imports or specific names):

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="dag",
    description="dag",
    # At 08:01 UTC (03:01 EST, 00:01 PST) on Monday
    # (https://crontab.guru/#1_8_*_*_1)
    schedule_interval="1 8 * * 1",
    catchup=False,
)


task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="handle",
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=handle,
    dag=dag,
    retries=2,
    retry_delay=timedelta(minutes=15),
    start_date=datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, pytz.UTC),
)
```

Any idea why this wouldn't have executed after the 2019-02-18 00:01 UTC interval?

Comment: Going to write an answer, I think it is correct. Not certain without the answer to my question above in the comments

Comment: Did it execute on Monday the following week?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:
The reason you do not see the run execute on the 18th is you have `catchup=False`

This will cause the DAG to skip backfill days if they have already passed. If you want to see the DAG fill in the 17th and the 24th you would need to set `catchup=True`

Airflow DAGs execute at the **END** of the **Schedule Interval**, so if your start date is the current Monday and your interval is every Monday, the DAG will not execute for this Monday’s run until the following Monday.

The main idea here is the data for the current Monday run is now available until the end of that interval period. This makes more sense of you think about it in terms of daily jobs. If you are running a job that is looking for today’s data, that data set will not be complete until the end of today. So if you want to run the data for today, you need to execute your job tomorrow. This is just a convention that Airflow has adopted, like it or not.

If you would like to adjust the dates, you can use `{{ macros.ds_add( ds, 7) }}` to shift the execution date by 7 days.

Let me know if this answer makes sense. If not I will expand on it. This convention has been the most nagging detail we have had to deal with while developing for Airflow jobs.

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting, I’m out of the office until Wednesday so I’ll check then. Everything you wrote makes sense and lines up with what I’ve read in the past, except in this case the start date was already offset by one interval. If you look at the definitions I posted, does it look like I set something up incorrectly?

Comment: It did run on Feb 25 but I’m still not sure why it didn’t run on the previous Monday given the start date.

Comment: Did you change the start date of the DAG after it had been added to the DAGs folder?

Comment: Do you have a delete DAG? I would try to delete all references to the DAG from your database. Airflow really does not like changing start dates. I have mixed results with changing schedule intervals. Especially if you changed the interval from something that was executing everyday to once per week. The DAG and schedule reference point are parsed into the DB the first time Airflow sees a DAG with that name. Any changes to it after it has run are difficult for the engine to understand.

Comment: No, the start date was originally added as `datetime(2019, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, pytz.UTC)` and was not changed. The only change made was was cron was set to `1 8 * * 1` from `1 8 */1 * 1`. I'm still not 100% sure I understand why the original cron caused the DAG to execute every day, even with taking the interval end into account.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the tree view of the DAG? Am curious what DAG runs are present.

Comment: WAIT. Adding to my answer. The edit you will see there is correct.

Comment: Ah, that does explain it, I had never really had a need for catchup and wasn't actually super familiar with it but now that I know that makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much!